# Delegate method, textViewDidChangeSelection not triggered everytime

Tags: swift, uitextviewdelegate, uitextinput

I have a UITextView embedded in a UITableView Cell, `CustomCell`. If I tap the return key when my curser is at the end of the text, I want to create a new cell below that cell, but if I tap return when I am in the middle of the textView, I want to get rest of the words after the curser and create a cell with that text in the textView.
To do that I need to know curser position in textView which I am getting with the help of the `UITextViewDelegate` method `textViewDidChangeSelection(_:)`.

It works only when I tap on different location on the same cell but if I move to a different cell and tap again on a previously tapped cell(in the textview)at the same position, the delegate method doesn't get triggered.

Let me show the case with an exapmle-

I type some texts for testing. Here, after the 5th line, I decide to tap on the 2nd line just before the word "juice" like -

[image]

The delegate method, `textViewDidChangeSelection(_:)` gets triggered.

Now, I click on the 3rd line after the whole text "Skim Milk" like-

[image]

and again the delegate method, `textViewDidChangeSelection(_:)` gets called.

But now when I move back to the 2nd line at the same position, meaning before the word “juice”, the delegate method doesn’t get triggered. Again if I tap on the 3rd line at the same position meaning after the word “milk”, the delegate method doesn't get called.

I think, the reason is in those cells, I tapped on the sane position, and as the selection didn’t get changed, the delegate method didn’t get called.
Following is the code for the delegate method which is in the `CustomCell`(UITableViewCell) class-

```
 func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView){
        if let range = textView.selectedTextRange, let indexPath = currentIndexPath{
            let curserStartPosition = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: range.start)
            setActiveCell?(indexPath, curserStartPosition)
        }
    }
```

The following is the code for the Controller where new cells are created when tapped the return key-

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
     var cellCount  = 1
     var initialCellText: String?
     var activeCell: CustomCell?
     var cursorPosition: Int?

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!{
        didSet{
            myTableView.delegate = self
            myTableView.dataSource = self
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
    }
    
    func goToNextCell(_ indexPath:IndexPath){

        let nextCelIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: 0)      
        if let text = activeCell?.myTextView.text, let cursorPos = cursorPosition, cursorPos < text.count-1 {
            let fromIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: cursorPos)
            let toIndex = text.index(text.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
        
        if fromIndex < toIndex {
            let truncatedText = text[fromIndex...toIndex]
            self.initialCellText = String(truncatedText)
        }
    }
    cellCount += 1
    myTableView.beginUpdates()
    myTableView.insertRows(at: [nextCelIndexPath], with: .none)
    myTableView.endUpdates()

    initialCellText = nil
    cursorPosition = nil
    
    if let cell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(at: nextCelIndexPath) as? CustomCell{
        self.activeCell = cell
        self.activeCell?.myTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
    func setActiveCell(on indexPath: IndexPath, at curserPos: Int){
        if let tappedOnCell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell{
            self.activeCell = tappedOnCell
            self.cursorPosition = curserPos
        }
    }   
}
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

extension MyViewController{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellCount
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as? CustomCell{
            cell.myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            cell.returnKeyTapped = goToNextCell(_:)
            cell.setActiveCell = setActiveCell(on:at:)
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

To  create the following cell, I need to know where the cursor position is on a particular cell everytime. So, I need the delegate method to be triggered everytime.

Can anyone have any suggestions as to how can I solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you basically want to know the curser position after you have typed into a `UITextView`.
Now, if you type into a `UITextView`, that text view becomes the first responder, and begins an editing session. This is announced by a `UITextView.textDidBeginEditingNotification` for which you can add an observer, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618612-textdidbegineditingnotification).
In the function called by the notification, you could compute the cursor position as you do in `textViewDidChangeSelection`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, implementing textViewDidBeginEditing, to calculate the curser also have an issue. It get triggered once only when I tap on the textView. If I change the text, it doesn't get triggered. So, for that case, textViewDidChangeSelection method gets me the position. So, rather than replacing, I had to add the textViewDidBeginEditing method.